# can't execute my node.js code using terminal

Tags: node.js

I've installed Node.js version 10.16.0 LTS. 
I run "node -v" command in cmd to check if it's installed correctly or not.

created a file hello.js
run cmd in the same directory

the error msg says:
D:\nodeJS>node

> node hello.js
>   Thrown:
>   node hello.js
>        ^^^^^
>   SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

the only line of code I wrote in .js file is : 
console.log("hello");

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    console.log("hello");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ran it in the node REPL. Press control + c twice to get out of the Node REPL. Then you run the command `node hello.js`

Comment: Great. Please mark my answer as correct. And you are welcome